# Split PHP variable using split or implode

Tags: php, variables, join, split, implode

I want to split the date variable in php.

Here I declare PHP variable like:
`$date = 20170501;`

and I want the result like this: 
`$date = 2017-05-01`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and easy way:

```
<?php
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("20170501"));
?>
```

Example: https://eval.in/819801